# How to split the words in oracle using regexp_substr?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string that containing 3 parts, the whole string is:

```
`aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.`
```

How can I get the 3 parts without the lower case character separately by using `regexp_substr` in oracle?

The result should be:

```
UNITED STATES :
USCOMPANY,
7/1990.
```

I have tried the following code.

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.', '[^a-z]+') 
from dual;
```

I can successfully get `UNITED STATES :`, but how can I get other results?

Comment: do you have these strings in a column? and do they all have the same exact pattern as shown?

Comment: Yes, the column contains all string that has the same exact pattern as shown.

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with? After you solve this, you may want to look into database design and normalizing tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','^a([^b]*)',1,1,'c',1)
       ,regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','b([^c]*)' ,1,1,'c',1)
       ,regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','c(.*)$'   ,1,1,'c',1)

from    dual
;
```

or

```
select  regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','[a-c]([^a-c]*)',1,1,'c',1)
       ,regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','[a-c]([^a-c]*)',1,2,'c',1)
       ,regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','[a-c]([^a-c]*)',1,3,'c',1)

from    dual
;
```

or

```
select  regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','[^a-c]*',1,2)
       ,regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','[^a-c]*',1,4)
       ,regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','[^a-c]*',1,6)

from    dual
;
```

or

```
select  regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','^a(.*?)b',1,1,'c',1)
       ,regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','b(.*?)c' ,1,1,'c',1)
       ,regexp_substr ('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','c(.*)$'  ,1,1,'c',1)

from    dual
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a combination of `substr` and `instr`, as the string pattern is consistent.

```
select 
--replace col with the column name from the table
substr(col,2,instr(col,':')-1) part_1,
substr(col,instr(col,':')+2,instr(col,',')-instr(col,':')-1) part_2,
substr(col,instr(col,',')+1) part_3
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Fisrt option. With regexp.

```
select regexp_substr('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','[a-z](.*)[a-z](.*)[a-z](.*)',1,1,null,1) 
     , regexp_substr('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','[a-z](.*)[a-z](.*)[a-z](.*)',1,1,null,2)
     , regexp_substr('aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.','[a-z](.*)[a-z](.*)[a-z](.*)',1,1,null,3)  
  from dual;
```

regexp_substr allow to extract regexp group from string [regexp_substr - desc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303). The group is define by 
brackets "(.......)".

2) xquery/xmltable

```
 select xmlcast(c.column_value as varchar2(200)) from xmltable('for $i in ora:tokenize($str,"[a-z]")
                                               where string-length($i) >0
                                                return $i' passing 'aUNITED STATES :bUSCOMPANY,c7/1990.' as "str" ) c;
```

`ora:tokenize($str,"[a-z]")` - split string into string sequnect using reg_exp pattern. 
Syntax inside xmltable is called "FLWOR Expressions"